# Java Generics get the Type from the method (that creates object) using reflection

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to create a GenericBuilder that could be used to retrieve the Builder classes that are defined inside my classes. I created the following interfaces and classes

```
public interface BuilderType<T> {
}

public class MyObject implements BuilderType<MyObject.MyObjectBuilder> {
private int i;
private MyObject() {}
public int getI() {
    return i;
}
public static MyObjectBuilder buildMyObject() {
    MyObjectBuilder builder = new MyObjectBuilder();
    return builder;
}
public static class MyObjectBuilder {
    private final MyObject obj;
    MyObjectBuilder() {
        obj = new MyObject();
    }
    public MyObjectBuilder withI(int i) {
        obj.i = i;
        return this;
    }
    public MyObject build() {
        return obj;
    }
}
public class GenericBuilder {
 public static <T extends BuilderType<S>, S> S getBuilder(Class<T> t) {
 S s = null;
 try {
     s = (S) t.getDeclaredMethod("build" + t.getSimpleName(), null)
                .invoke(null, null);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return s;
 }
}
```

the statement s=(S)t.get... in my GenericBuilder gives a cast warning: Unchecked Cast from Object to S, is there a way to eliminate it??

Comment: usually we do `if instanceof SomeClass` for unchecked cast. Just this is warning cant you skip it ?

Comment: Yes I can actually skip it, but just wanted to know whether there is a way to get over it, and also I think instanceof cannot be used in generic context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to eliminate the warning because `S` is not a real type. By runtime it will get erased to its upper bound, which is `Object` in your case. So the "downcast" isn't actually doing anything. You can check the `Method`'s return type by calling the appropriate method, and then do a reflective downcast (not very helpful for your scenario). Type safety cannot possibly be achieved when you dynamically fetch a method at runtime.

Comment: Yeah but during type erasure S will be substituted by Object, so it will become Object s = (Object) t.getDeclared..., So its Object being assigned to Object? so where does the downcast occur? so what is a reflective downcast?

Comment: The downcast occurs only at the call site, so you can expect a runtime `ClassCastException` thrown from the call site. A reflective downcast uses the method `Class.cast()`.